# Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded Laravel

Tags: laravel, breeze, laravel-9

i got this error when click on password reset button which used with laravel breeze package

```
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

my .env file settings

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=68dbabddexxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=945bc275exxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="support@test.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

what should i do to solve this problem ?

consider :

1- max_execution_time = 300
2- mail server configuration has been check

Comment: Can you try another ports? 25 or 465 or 587?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "Maximum execution time exceeded" error typically occurs when your code takes too long to execute, and in this case,

Increase the maximum execution time:
In your `php.ini` file or in your Laravel application's `.htaccess` file, set the `max_execution_time` directive to a higher value, such as 120 or 180 seconds:

```
max_execution_time = 180
```

You Can also use queue driver in this case

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues

A mail queue driver efficiently manages the sending of emails by organizing them in a queue and ensuring they are sent out in the proper order. It handles tasks such as connecting to the mail server, formatting emails, and dispatching them for delivery. This allows applications to delegate the email sending process to a separate component, improving performance and ensuring reliable delivery.